# jibx : how to remove the word "List" from auto generated java collections?

Tags: java, list, auto-generate, jibx

I'm using jibx to auto generate java classed based on a xsd schema.
In this schema I have a collection called markets:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"
name="markets" nillable="true" type="market"/>
```

When I run jibx (using maven plugin) the result is a java class with the following collection:

```
 private List<Market> marketList = new ArrayList<Market>();
/** 
     * Get the list of 'markets' element items.
     * 
     * @return list
     */
    public List<Market> getMarketList() {
        return marketList;
    }

    /** 
     * Set the list of 'markets' element items.
     * 
     * @param list
     */
    public void setMarketList(List<Market> list) {
        marketList = list;
    }
```

What I'd like to have is the name of the element and the getter and setter without the word List, but instead with the word markets setMarkets() and getMarkets().

I know I can specify a custom file in the pom.xml :

```
<customizations>
<customizations>src/main/config/custom1.xml</customizations>
</customizations>
```

But I don't know how to specify the behavior I need in the custom1.xml.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Marco,
You are correct, you need to use an extension customization. There are two ways to replace the method name:

1. Use the strip-suffixes command.
   Your customization file would look something like this

   `<schema-set xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <name-converter strip-suffixes="List"/>

   </schema-set>>`
2. Write a name-converter
   If you want your method to be getMarkets instead of getMarket.

Here's the documentation for what you want to do from the JiBX web site:
http://jibx.sourceforge.net/fromschema/codegen-extends.html
Don
JiBX contributor